# What is the recommended design pattern for Flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, architecture

I was wondering if there are any recommended design patterns for flutter applications from the official flutter dev team. For example google recommends the MVVM pattern for android applications.

I already searched the flutter docs but didnt find any information about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked around for some answers and it looks like that there is no official recommended design pattern until now for flutter applications.

Anyway I suggest everyone trying out the [BLoC Pattern](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/), which i used in my own application and proved to be very good. It´s gives you a clear and simple understanding of your application later on and is highly testable.

Comment: as for now, the Provider is the recommended approach from Flutter https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options#provider